# How to split Javascript and HTML Files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, model-view-controller

im working at the moment with jQuery Mobile. Whats the best way to split the Javascript and the HTML Files? Its possible to create single Views, and load them with Ajax into the code?

Example:

view.html

```
<li>
    <img src="{$image}" alt="{$title}" /> {$title}
</li>
```

Javascript Code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.channels.length; i++)
{
    var url = data.channels[i].url,
    image = data.channels[i].image,
    title = data.channels[i].name;

    // load view.html and replace variables in each loop, than append view into an div
}
```

It could be also an MVC Framework that is working well with jQuery Mobile. Thank you!

Comment: Yes it is possible, but how this answer helps you?

Comment: Could you say me also how? The problem is that i have a lot Javascript code in the hole WebAPP, and some views are used in more pages.

Comment: The problem is not in the views, but how you will pass a server variables to them. You have to have a controller, that will manage this. As i see you use Smarty in your views.

Comment: Whats about loading the view into a variable, and replace the variables of the view with .replace()? Could you tell me a nice way to load the view into a variable?

Comment: This is not a way to do that.

Comment: @bksi I have found a Solution now, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a very nice solution for Splitting HTML and Javascript files with jquery.tmpl!

It is an official supported Plugin: https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl

I have now the whole HTML in single files.

Example:

templates/channel_row.html

```
<li>
    <a href="somelink.html?id=${id}" data-transition="slide">
        <img src="#" data-src="${image}" alt="" class="ui-li-icon ui-corner-none" />
        ${name}
    </a>
</li>
```

And i am calling this file with:

```
// array with all channels
var channels = [];

for(var i = 0; i < data.channels.length; i++)
{
    // data
    var channel = {
        id: data.channels[i].id,
        name: data.channels[i].name,
        image: data.channels[i].image
    };

    // ad channel to array
    channels.push(channel);
}

$.get("templates/channel_row.html", function(template) {
        $.tmpl(template, channels).appendTo("#listview_channels");
});
```

I hope that I have helped you.

Answer (score 1):

I think AngularJS would allow such kind of data binding: http://angularjs.org/

Apparently you also need some kind of adapter: https://github.com/opitzconsulting/jquery-mobile-angular-adapter

For having multiple js files in general I would recommend RequireJS (I don't know if AngularJS has its own solution for the problem require solves.